# TCPClient. How do I receive big messages?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I have the following code:

```
private string Connect()
{
    string responseData;

    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ServerIp, Port);
        client.ReceiveBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

        Byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(ReadyQuery);


        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        // send data
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


        // buffer
        data = new Byte[65536];               

        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(data, 0, bytes);                

        // close all
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
```

I have problem with a big message. The receive message size is 22K chars. I get only part of message.
How can I receive big messages?

PS. In the debugger `bytes` equal `4096`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call stream.Read in a loop until you read the entire message. If you know the message size in advance it's relatively easy:

```
int messageSize = 22000;
int readSoFar = 0;
byte [] msg = new byte[messageSize];

while(readSoFar < messageSize)
{
    var read = stream.Read(msg, readSoFar, msg.Length - readSoFar);
    readSoFar += read;
    if(read==0)
        break;   // connection was broken
}
```

If the message size is part of the message (say, encoded in the first 4 bytes), you should read those first and then do as I suggested.

Comment: As an addition: If you don't know the message size in advance, it's always a good idea to use some "message terminator". For example, you might append an `ETX` character at the end so the client knows that when `ETX` is contained in the message, the message is over.

Comment: That's good for textual messages. Binary messages are trickier.

Comment: You're right - but in his code he's converting the received result to string, so I doubt he's sending binary messages.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, server send size in begining of message.

Comment: OK. Just remember that when reading the message size you might not get the entire size (2 or 4 bytes), but just a part of it. It's highly unlikely, but it can happen. You need the same trick for reading the fixed-length length field.