# How to set length of byteBuffer for incoming data so it is enough big?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, bitmap, buffer

I am sending jpg via tcp:

On the sender side we got:

```
 private void sendResponse() {

        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\a.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
        byte[] data;
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmi));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }

        clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

but how should I set buffer size on the other side(receiver side)?

I got buffer set for 4096 bytes which is obviously wrong:

```
public string Receive() {
            string response = "Operation Timeout";
            if (connection != null) {

                connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = connection.RemoteEndPoint;
                connectArgs.SetBuffer(new Byte[4096], 0, 4096);

                connectArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
                    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
                      BITMAP DECODING
                    } else {
                        response = e.SocketError.ToString();

                    }
                    _clientDone.Set();
                });
                _clientDone.Reset();
                connection.ReceiveAsync(connectArgs);
                _clientDone.WaitOne(3000);

            } else {
                response = "Socket is not initialized";
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact size of the data, set the buffer to that size. If not, set it to something reasonable and read from the stream until it's empty.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680962/tcpclient-how-do-i-receive-big-messages) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sebastian Negraszus. You can add your own data formatting (application protocol).

For example you can first send the size of the data you're trying to transmit. Say, it will be 4 bytes (size of the int type). The other end will know that it has to read 4 bytes from network to know the amount of data to expect from the stream.

After data size is known at the other end - memory allocation should not be a problem.